# How to fix sts 4 application.properties content assist

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I have installed `sts-4`. When I tried to edit in `application.properties`, content assist is not working.

For example: for writing `server.port=8090`, if we try to write `ser` and press ctrl+space, it should suggest the correct property, but that functionality is not working

Comment: This is hard to answer without further details. Which version of Spring Tools 4 do you use? It this doesn't work for a freshly installed Spring Tools 4.3.2 for Eclipse distribution, you should file a report at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and attach a sample project that helps us to reproduce the issue and some detailed steps how to reproduce this. You could update your question here with more details and detailed steps how to reproduce this problem.

Comment: sts 4.3.2 is installed. Just created a project from start.spring.io. Imported created project in this sts. In application.properties file, i have tried server. and did cntrl+space, no suggestions are coming

Comment: Did you import/create the project using the 'New Spring Starter' wizard in STS, or create it yourself on the start.spring.io site and then manually import in STS? If so, I suggest you instead use the wizard to ensure the project is imported and configured correctly. If you already did it this way, then I'm not sure. But it still sounds like something isn't quite right with the project setup. If STS doesn't have classpath data it won't be able to suggest properties. And usually this means something in the project is 'broken' causing classpath data to be missing.

Comment: If you use the 'New Spring Starter' wizard and it still doesn't work for you, please zip up the entire contents of the project and share it with us. May be best to create a issue ticket in our bug tracker as Martin suggested. But if you can share it here, we can try to help here as well.